# Why is my ng-repeat acting like the object is empty?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube-api

Here is my controller code:

```
.controller('vidController', ["$scope", "$location", "youtubeAPI", function($scope, $location, youtubeAPI) {
    if(document.getElementById('query')) { //See Note 1 Below*****
        var textElement = document.getElementById('query');
        textElement.onkeyup=function(e){ 
            if(e.keyCode==13){ //if key pressed is enter button
                console.log('Looking for ' + textElement.value + ' on YouTube');
                youtubeAPI.search(textElement.value);
                $location.path('/results'); //changes url path to results partial
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        }
    };
    // Called automatically with the response of the YouTube API request.
    window.onSearchResponse = function(response) {
        console.log(response); //Shows entire response data
        console.log(response.items[0].snippet.title); //shows video title
        console.log(response.items[0].id.videoId); //shows video Id
        console.log(response.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.medium.url); //shows video thumbnail
        $scope.videos = response.items;
        $scope.$apply();
        console.log($scope.videos); //This outputs an object with 5 Objects in it. Proof that the API is picking up something.
    };
}]);
```

*Note 1: I have an input text type that the user puts their search keyword into and then presses enter to run the search on it, it also changes the address when the enter key is pressed. Maybe this is causing an issue?

And here is the partial:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="video in videos">
    hey
    </li>
</ul>
```

Since i'm using the youtubeAPI, every search result brings back 5 results. `console.log($scope.video)` shows in the console the 5 objects, so I know it's being populated.

However whenever I go to my partial page and inspect element, the `<ul>` tags are completely empty. like the `ng-repeat` never ran.

Why would it not run? I should be seeing "hey" 5 times.

EDIT: Here's a console output of the last console.log in my code
[image]

EDIT 2: Upon request, here is where onSearchResponse is run.

```
angular.module('GameFindr.search', [])
.factory('youtubeAPI', [function() {

var youtubeAPI = { };

youtubeAPI.search = function(keyword) {
    // Use the JavaScript client library to create a search.list() API call.
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        q: keyword,
        type: 'video',
    });

    // Send the request to the API server,
    // and invoke onSearchRepsonse() with the response.
    request.execute(onSearchResponse);
    }

    return youtubeAPI;
}]);
```

EDIT 3: Adding `$scope.apply();` after `$scope.videos` works if I comment out the `$location.path` change, and it stays on the same view. But it doesn't work when I change views. Here is my router:

```
angular.module('GameFindr', [
'ngRoute',
'GameFindr.controllers',
'GameFindr.search'
])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/', { templateUrl: 'home.html', controller: 'vidController' }).
    when('/results', { templateUrl: 'results.html', controller: 'vidController'}).
    otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
 }]);
```

Comment: May be its running outside angular's knowledge and hence `ng-repeat` is not updating. Try `$scope.$apply()` before your `console.log` and see what you get.

Comment: I've tried this, it did not help unfortunately

Comment: Where exactly does this function (`onSearchResponse`) run? Show more of the code

Comment: added youtube API call that searches and calls onSearchResponse

Comment: try defining a `$scope.videos = []` at beginning

Comment: No affect it seems, still empty

Comment: Maybe you've forgot to specify ng-controller="vidController" in your html code? 
Or the ng-repeat is not inside the controller?

Comment: @alexeiTruhin One of the previous posters pointed that out but he deleted his suggestion, unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Added some more information to the original question, the controller code on the question is now my entire controller.js code (minue the angular.module declaration)

Comment: can you please put the $scope.apply() at the end of the function "window.onSearchResponse" where you are getting the videos by logging $scope.videos? I think when you are starting the digest cyle in the onKeyUp function at that time your api responses are not coming yet. so you have to start the digest cycle after you're getting the response from youtube api.

Answer (score 1):

you are changing the the object value in callback, so by the time the value is available from callback the ng-repeat it getting run already with initial value and which is undefined in your case.

Try below code

```
$scope.videos = response.items;
$scope.$apply();
```

Ref: github
$scope.$apply() called at the end, to tell AngularJS that an asynchronous event just occurred.

Comment: I'm getting inconsistent results. Sometimes this works, sometimes it doesn't. Any idea whats going on?

Comment: for ''inconsistent results'' what are you getting in console for $scope.videos? or any error?

Comment: $scope.videos always gives me the correct information, but sometimes the "hey" runs 5 times and sometimes it doesn't. I've added some more information to my original post, maybe it will be useful